# Cannot query ACF Options page with GraphQL and GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, graphql, advanced-custom-fields, gatsby

I am trying to query my ACF options page fields that I have set up in the admin side, and through the WP API Query them using GatsbyJS's `gatsby-source-wordpress`. When I run build and dev it requests the data and prints out the output

```
=== [ Fetching wordpress__acf_options ] === http://url.local/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options/
⠈ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__acf_options fetched : 1
Fetching the wordpress__acf_options took: 518.885ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__acf_options ] === http://url.local/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options
⠈ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__acf_options fetched : 1
Fetching the wordpress__acf_options took: 478.580ms
```

and within those urls on the browser, I get this response. So I know the data is correct

```
 {
        acf: {
            social_options: [
                {
                     social_name: "Twitter ",
                     social_link: "https://twitter.com"
                },
                {
                     social_name: "Linkedin",
                     social_link: "https://www.linkedin.com/"
                }
            ],
            test: "pagfe 1"
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I query the `allWordpressAcfOptions` in the internal GraphQL. I try and see what options are available to query but all I can get is the `ID`. This is my query below.

```
{
  allWordpressAcfOptions {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        internal {
          type
          contentDigest
          owner
        }
        children {
          id
        }
        wordpress_id
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

and none of the data in there is the data I need, an none of it is representative of the same data shown from REST API Link. So there is something missing. This is the response I get back from the Query.

```
{
  "data": {
    "allWordpressAcfOptions": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "038ece9f-326d-5bb0-8f17-1bb72ce06c57",
            "internal": {
              "type": "wordpress__acf_options",
              "contentDigest": "10b2729a5f87723bbafc539f99fb23d6",
              "owner": "gatsby-source-wordpress"
            },
            "children": [],
            "wordpress_id": "acf"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For reference my `gatsby-source-wordpress` options in the gatsby config are this below

```
options: {
    baseUrl: 'url.local',
    protocol: 'http',
    hostingWPCOM: false,
    useACF: true,
    acfOptionPageIds: ['options'],
    verboseOutput: true
},
```

`options` refers to the page ID the my ACF options page is set in my functions.php on the wordpress side.

So in summary, GatsbyJs is referencing the API and pulling the data but what am I doing wrong to query the data via GraphQL?

Comment: Did you try using the graphql console and diving deeper into the result tree to see what is available under the schema?

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Yes you can see the results tree that were available in the original post where it reads `allWordpressAcfOptions` - but it show no data related to the endpoint in question

Comment: is that the complete schema? you're probably missing something. The details provided are insufficient

Comment: @itaintme I agree, but what other Schema would I call to get the ACf options data?

Comment: @SamKelham can't say without looking at the schema. Look around, you'll probably find something